# SSRS: can't load default filter value for input

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My report contains a dataset which is used to load default values per user. I'm manually putting an id and respective values parameters are loaded (or should be) as a default (and later available for edit). The dataset that sets a filter values has User ID and Profile as input parameters (it's a procedure that returns one row with values, and then I assign them to filter fields default values).

Each User has his own set of Measures and measures values which I want to be filled and editable when User ID is modified. The scenario of use is described below.

When I'm starting a Preview of the report, I'm able to enter a user ID (and then to modify it); Measure1 and Measure2 are constant (by Available Values filter) as wanted but I want to manipulate with their values Measure1_q1, Measure1_q2,... (which are also loaded by default).

[image]

[image]

I partially receive what I want, when I switch a value filter field (e.g. Measure1_q1) to "Available value" mode. The value is switching, but I can't modify it, what is the main requirement in my case.

[image]

[image]

I thought about cascade filters, but it would need to load all values of all users to the dataset and then filter out the one I will type, I don't want to do this.

Comment: I believe cascading parameters is the only way you can get this to work as it is the only process that runs after selecting an available value.  It would have to be something like case statements against the Measure 1 and Measure 2 parameters.

Comment: without Cascading Parameters.. SSRS does not refresh parameters based on parent parameter - in your case the USER ID. It can have defaults.. but it won't refresh when you change the USER ID parameter..